# C++11: Table of Function Pointers, Lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, types, lambda, function-pointers

I'm currently working on a simple and abstract emulator for processors, and I'm using a table to translate machine-code opcodes into actions. Currently, this table holds pointers to delegate functions (provided by an external library), which are the only option I had at the time (before C++11) to make it possible to call member functions of subclass instances.

So far, Lambdas look like they can provide a perfect replacement, but I still want to support vanilla function pointers. This tutorial on lambdas shows an example where you can treat lambdas and function pointers identically, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to store a mixed array of function pointers and lambdas so I can also store them in the same place.

Comment: Stateless lambdas (i.e., without capture) can be converted to function pointers. So you can store both function pointers and stateless lambdas in an array of function pointers.

Comment: Can stateless lambdas be "bound" to a specific instance of a class so that it accesses its members (and have the same lambda somehow re-constructed by another function to point at a different instance of the same class)?

Comment: In a stateless lambda, the only variables you can access are static local and namespace scope variables (as well as the lambda's parameters).

Comment: So I couldn't use just plain function pointers, but I can settle with std::function, depending on exactly how much overhead there is.

Comment: You could pass the instance as a parameter to the lambda/function pointer.

Comment: unfortunately, that would mean that the processor would have to know what objects it's associated with, which would violate one of the design principles my project is following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is a mechanism to do type erasure for all things callable.

You can have a collection of std::function and put in function pointers with that signature next to lambdas with that signature. There is a bit of overhead involved compared to using function pointers directly. It's interesting to note that the type of a lambda not specified by the spec and therefore cannot be written down directly, but it can always be put in a std::function wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering though, how significant the overhead is when compared to using function pointers (the selection and calling of functions from this table is the core of my emulated processor's functionality, and while I don't need really high-speed stuff, I need to make sure that this doesn't become a bottleneck).

Comment: It hasn't been enough that I've had to find out just how much overhead there is. I'd only be worried about it in extreme cases where you're inside a really tight loop that has to be fast or something.

Comment: Yep. The processor runs in a loop, executing one instruction after another. Every time it executes an instruction, it needs to look through this table of functions and run one of them. EDIT: But I'm not sure precisely how fast I need it.